# Getting a 404 when I click on the answer anchor link

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I am getting a 404 when I click on the answer link in the card.pug file.

```
extends layout.pug

block content
section#content
h2= text
if hint
  p
    i Hint: #{hint}
 a(href=`${id}?side=${sideToShow}`)= sideToShowDisplay
```

The routing file for the card.pug file is the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { data } = require('../data/flashcardData.json');
const { cards } = data;

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
const { side } = req.query;
const { id } = req.params;
const text = cards[id][side];
const { hint } = cards[id];

const templateData = { id, text };

if (side === 'question') {
templateData.hint = hint;
templateData.sideToShow = 'answer';
templateData.sideToShowDisplay = 'Answer';
} else if (side === 'answer') {
templateData.sideToShow = 'question';
templateData.sideToShowDisplay = 'Question';
}

res.render('card', templateData);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm not sure why this has done this.  Any help would be much appreciated. It is pulling data from a JSON file which is in a data folder.

Comment: First, find out whether the problem is in the client or the server. Where does the link actually redirect to? Is that the right URL? If so, then ignore the pug file and treat this as a question about the express code. If not, it's a question about the pug file.

Comment: I've noticed in the query string it repeats the id. http://localhost:3000/cards/4/4?side=answer . As you can see the problem is id is repeated before the ? mark.

Comment: So it seems the problem is client-side: `id` should be `/cards/4` and instead it's `/cards/4/4`. Can you show where `layout.pug` is called from?

Comment: ```doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title flash Cards
  body
    include includes/header.pug
    block content
    include includes/footer.pug
```

Comment: Any ideas on how I can fix this David?

Comment: I'm assuming `id` is wrong, but I don't know how it was set. Look for `id` in whichever file includes/references `card.pug`. (I said `layout.pug` in my last message; I should have said `card.pug`.)

Comment: Oh, I get it. `card.pug` is called from `res.render('card', templateData);`. If you do `console.log('id is', id);` after `id` is defined, what do you get?

Answer (score -1):

You can use anchor `href = ' user single code here'`

Example

```
a(href=`${id}?side=${sideToShow}`)= sideToShowDisplay
```

Instead of above use below

```
a(href='${id}?side=${sideToShow}')= sideToShowDisplay
```

It works for me